# jQuery - Execute timer only if window is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am trying to do, whenever someone clicks on a link I've got, it will open a new page. Once the page is opened, I want a progress bar and a timer to count down to zero.

The thing is, I only want the countdown and the progress bar to count down / run when the window is active. When the window / tab is not active, I want the timer / progress bar to stop.

I can't get it to work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
var time = <?php echo $time; ?>
$(function() {
        $('#iframe').load(function() {
            startCounter();

            $('#iframe').unbind('load');
        });
    });
    var isActive = true;
    window.onfocus = function() { isActive = true; };
    window.onblur = function() { isActive = false; };



    function checkfocus() {
        if(isActive = true){
            time=time-1;        
        } else {

        }   

    }
    function startCounter() {
        $('#counter').fadeOut('fast');
        setTimeout("$('#counter').fadeIn('fast')",1050);
        setTimeout("runCounter()",1000);

    }

    function runCounter() {

        if(time==0){
            $('#counter').html('<button class="butn blue" onclick="<?php echo $creditButtonName; ?>();">Click here to get credited!</button>');
        }
        else {
            $('#counter').html('You must view this advertisement for ' + time + ' more seconds!');
            startBar();                                                                     
            setTimeout("checkfocus()", 1000);   
            setTimeout("runCounter()",1000);

        }


    }


function startBar(){
    $('#bar').animate({
        width:'100%'
    }, <?php echo $time; ?>000);
}
```

At the moment the timer will just count down. Not stop when the window is not active or anything.

My other problem is: how can I do so the progress bar will also stop animating when the window is not active, and then start again when it is?

Comment: You might want to check out this plugin which handles detecting page visibility more reliably than window.onfocus/window.onblur: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-visibility

Comment: Rather than using the timed check of focus, use onfocus() function for keeping all your functions and processes active. It will automatically solve your problem.

Comment: `if(isActive = true){` That's assignment, not comparison, and will always evaluate to true. You should be using `if(isActive == true){` (note the double equals). Voting to close because this seems to just be a typo question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a typo in the code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What typo?

Comment: @oliverbj Using `=` (assigning true as the value of the variable) rather than `==` (comparing the value of the variable against true). I assumed that was a typo, but it could also be a logic error because you don't know the difference. Either way that's not a useful question for anybody else.